# What is the Buddhist perspective on body language?

Tags: karma, meditation-body

Some explain that body language affects qualities like leadership, command, personality etc.:

[Your body language shapes who you are](http://www.ted.com/talks/amy_cuddy_your_body_language_shapes_who_you_are)

What is the Buddhist perspective on body language? Does body language affect mental qualities?

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples in Buddha's life how others were inspired by his appearance.
King Bimbisara was tempted to offer him a palace seeing his stature on the first encounter (this was before his enlightenment),

> Look at this one, sirs. How handsome, stately, pure! How consummate
>   his demeanor! Mindful, his eyes downcast, looking only a plow-length
>   before him, as one who's not from a lowly lineage: Send the royal
>   messengers at once to see where this monk will go.
>
> [..]
>
> "You are young, youthful, in the first stage of youth, endowed with
>   the stature & coloring    of a noble-warrior. You would look glorious
>     in the vanguard of an army,     arrayed with an elephant squadron. I
>   offer you wealth : enjoy it. I ask your birth : inform me."
>
> [Sn 3.1](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.3.01.than.html)

Maha Kassapa accepted him as his teacher without hearing a word from him,

> On the road between Rajagaha and Nalanda, the Master sat down under a
>   fig tree, waiting for his future disciple. When Kassapa arrived at the
>   spot and saw the radiance of the Buddha's countenance, sensing the
>   enlightenment that shone through it, he thought, "This must be my
>   Master for whose sake I have gone forth!" He approached the Buddha,
>   and paying homage, fell at his feet and exclaimed: "The Exalted One,
>   Lord, is my teacher, and I am his disciple!"
>
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/hecker/wheel345.html#ch4

The occasion where Milinda was introduced to Nâgasena in [Milinda panha](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/sbe35/sbe3503.htm#page_36) gives some insight on how Buddhist literature sees the influence of body language.
Nâgasena was a junior monk, yet Milinda was able to recognize him among others by his demeanor,

> And as he looked over the whole of the assembly, in front, and down the centre,
>   and behind, king Milinda detected Nâgasena seated in the middle, and,
>   *like a shaggy lion who knows no fear or frenzy, entirely devoid of
>   nervous agitation, and free from shyness and trepidation*. And as soon
>   as he saw him, he knew by his mien that that was Nâgasena, and he
>   pointed him out to Devamantiya.

Now, this is a king that gets nervous and frightened by the sight of a monk.

> Whereupon the king rejoiced that he had recognised Nâgasena without having had him pointed out to him. But nevertheless, at *the sight of him, the king was seized with nervous excitement and trepidation and fear.*

This encounter conditions the king's mind, the king has accepted defeat by the very sight of this monk.

> 'At the sight of Nâgasena, wise and pure, Subdued in all that is the
>   best subjection, Milinda uttered this foreboding word-- "*Many the
>   talkers I have visited, Many the conversations I have had, But never
>   yet, till now, to-day, has fear, So strange, so terrible, o'erpowered
>   my heart*. Verily now defeat must be my lot, And victory his, so
>   troubled is my mind".

Comment: Great answer. I was looking more on how this influence one or the other maybe using dependent origination or abidhamma. Anyway a great answer.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala You should have mentioned it in the question no? I think it's better to delete the answer then. I have no issues with that :)

Comment: Please leave the answer. You can perhaps add some more to it as this answers about 60% of what I was looking for.

Comment: "How is this instrumented?" part is only missing.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala Ok I guess the answer for that is more in abhidhamma, how positive thoughts relate to generating rupa kalapa, which I'm not so familiar with.

Comment: No worries. Your answer gives solid basis for further investigation.